# Can installed Java JDK has bad influence on another SomeCode.bat File?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, java-8

I installed Java JDK and tried to code something and realized, that when I am using now some .bat codes I was used to work with (completely different project), I am getting for some cases "is not recognized as an internal or external command" on completely different commands I had no problems at all.

Question is simple though...

Is possible, that installing of JDK has bad influence on different codes or anything which runs in Windows 7?

Sorry for not putting more info, but those .bat codes are not done by me.

Comment: It is possible, especially if the installation changed some environment variables etc. However it is hard to give an answer with the information you provided.

Comment: Well it could changed your PATH variable

Comment: If your PATH is correct, you shouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Actually I changed the Path, so I can use "javac" in everywhere in cmd pompt....

Comment: Thank you everyone for input. I don't know what more info I could provide, so sorry (you can at least inform me for next time which info). I added default paths to this **PATH** and now it is ok! SOLVED